# How to change the cursor's shape without using MouseArea?

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2, mouse-cursor, qtquickcontrols

I looked over the similar threads but it didn't help much.

I'm using `QtQuick.Controls.Button` in `QML` and I cannot change the cursor shape when hovering over the button! I want to achieve this without using `MouseArea`. What can be done? As I looked over the documentation I couldn't find a, say, `cursorShape` property or similar.

Comment: Submit a patch to Qt to add the property new need? ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is kind of a hack, but you can access the `Button`'s own `MouseArea` via the `__behavior` pseudo-private property.

```
Button {
    text: qsTr("Hello World")
    Component.onCompleted: __behavior.cursorShape = Qt.PointingHandCursor
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can very easily create your own improved `Button`:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

Button {
    property alias cursorShape: mouseArea.cursorShape

    MouseArea
    {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPressed:  mouse.accepted = false
    }
}
```

Note that you may have to explicitly import the QML module where you defined `Button` in order to overshadow the `QtQuick.Controls`'s `Button`.